# Use random variable is Wp query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I'm calling wo query with shortcode and twice on same page but pagination of one wp query automatically changing other in posts as well,
How can I use a random variable for wp query so each shortcode have different pagination will not affect each another

Answer (score 0):

Try with add `orderby => rand` like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name'  => 'test', //catname
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // no. of posts
    'orderby'        => 'rand', // auto select post
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

where 'rand' should give you a random order of your posts.

For more info check out the Codex on WP_Query order parameters [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

Comment: Thanks! but you don't understand my question, Assume I'm calling $args on one page twice, but I don't want to use $args for both, I want different var for each time I call WP_Query